# clarification needed on document public List<HitResult> hitTest (float xPx, float yPx)

Tags: frame, hittest, arcore

The on-line document on hitTest says:

```
public List<HitResult> hitTest (float xPx, float yPx)
..............................
Parameters
xPx x coordinate in pixels
yPx y coordinate in pixels
.................................
```

However, I do not know in which coordinate system these pixel value are in regards.

Background:
we obtained a 2D point using computer vision algorithm based on the `arcore` `computervision_java` sample. The image obtained is `1280x720` in resolution and is from `GPU`. We need to find the intersection 3D coordinate of the `2D_point` with the plane from Frame. however the result of `hitTest` is not we expected.

I am guessing that maybe the hitTest need to use an image from Frame (`640x480` in resolution). We have also tried to scale the pixel coordinate from `1280x720` down to `640x480`, but the result is still not make any sense to us.

Thank you.   Peter Yin

Answer (score 0):

I fully agree that the documentation of

```
public List<HitResult> hitTest (float xPx, float yPx)
```

is vague. But the [documentation of the overloaded method](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/com/google/ar/core/Frame.html#hitTest(float[],%20int,%20float[],%20int))

```
public List<HitResult> hitTest (float[] origin3, int originOffset, float[] direction3, int directionOffset)
```

says

> Similar to hitTest(float, float), but takes an arbitrary ray in world space coordinates instead of a screen-space point.

Hence, the parameters of the method `hitTest (float xPx, float yPx)` ought to be in **screen space**. Changing the method signature to  `hitTest (float screenSpaceX, float screenSpaceY)` would be a lot more informative and readable.

Along with

```
Rect displaySize = new Rect();
((WindowManager)getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE))
  .getDefaultDisplay().getRectSize(displaySize);
```

giving you the screen size, you should be able to perform correct `hitTest(float, float)` invocations.